# Linker Error (MEX could not find the OpenCV library)

Tags: c++, c, matlab, opencv, mex

I'm using MATLAB R2013a x64 and Win7 x64. I installed OpenCV 2.4.7.2 to the path (C:\opencv). Previous compile errors with `round` are solved, but now there is a linking error.

MEX command output:

```
>> mex -LC:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib -IC:\opencv\build\include\opencv -lcv -lcxcore me_HaarDetectOpenCV.cpp

Warning: MEX could not find the library "cv" specified with -l option. 
         MEX looked for a file with one of the names: 
               cv.lib 
               libcv.lib 
         MEX looked for the library in the following directories: 
               D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\LIB\amd64 
               D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64 
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x64 
               D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\lib\win64 
               D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft 
               C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib 

Warning: MEX could not find the library "cxcore" specified with -l option. 
         MEX looked for a file with one of the names: 
               cxcore.lib 
               libcxcore.lib 
         MEX looked for the library in the following directories: 
               D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\LIB\amd64 
               D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\ATLMFC\LIB\amd64 
               C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\lib\win8\um\x64 
               D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\lib\win64 
               D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\lib\win64\microsoft 
               C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\lib 

     Creating library C:\Users\AsUs\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_47j5SQ\templib.x and object C:\Users\AsUs\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_47j5SQ\templib.exp 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateImage referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseImage referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateMemStorage referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseMemStorage referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvGetSeqElem referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvLoad referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvEqualizeHist referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvHaarDetectObjects referenced in function mexFunction 
  me_HaarDetectOpenCV.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals 

    D:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'me_HaarDetectOpenCV.mexw64' failed. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully. 
>>
```

How do I fix the error and compile (create the MEX file `me_HaarDetectOpenCV.mexw64`)?

---

i'm edit [`me_HaarDetectOpenCV.Cpp`](http://pastebin.com/r36FXZDk) and fix error .

```
#include "D:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013a\extern\include\mex.h"
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\cv.h" 
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\highgui.h"
#include "C:\opencv\build\include\opencv\cxcore.h"
```

MEX command output:

```
>> mex me_HaarDetectOpenCV.cpp
   Creating library C:\Users\AsUs\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_7BQNq1\templib.x and object C:\Users\AsUs\AppData\Local\Temp\mex_7BQNq1\templib.exp 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseMemStorage referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseHaarClassifierCascade referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseImage referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvGetSeqElem referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvHaarDetectObjects referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvEqualizeHist referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateMemStorage referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvCreateImage referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvLoad referenced in function mexFunction 
me_HaarDetectOpenCV.mexw64 : fatal error LNK1120: 9 unresolved externals 

  D:\PROGRA~2\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'me_HaarDetectOpenCV.mexw64' failed. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.
```

Comment: Please copy whatever is on the paste board into the question - that means future readers are not dependent on links that might break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in previous comments, your code is using the old C interface of OpenCV. It is preferred to use the newer C++ interface.

Perhaps it is best to show a complete example. The code below runs face detecting using the Haar-based [cascade classifier](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html). I simplified it from your code a bit by removing some of the parameters parsing.

If you want an easier wrapper for using OpenCV inside MATLAB, consider using [`mexopencv`](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv).

#### faces.cpp

```cpp
#include "mex.h"
#include <string>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // validate arguments
    if (nrhs < 2) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of input arguments.");
    }
    if (nlhs > 1) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");
    }
    if (!mxIsChar(prhs[0]) || mxGetM(prhs[0])!=1) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("First argument must be a string.");
    }
    if (!mxIsUint8(prhs[1]) || mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0])!=2) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Second argument must be a uint8 grayscale image.");
    }

    // get XML cascade file name
    char *xmlfile = mxArrayToString(prhs[0]);
    cv::CascadeClassifier cascade;
    if (!cascade.load(std::string(xmlfile))) {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Failed to load cascade classifier.");
    }
    mxFree(xmlfile);

    // get grayscale image
    mwSize nrows = mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    mwSize ncols = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
    uint8_T *data = reinterpret_cast<uint8_T*>(mxGetData(prhs[1]));

    // copy into an OpenCV mat (there are better ways to do this step!)
    cv::Mat img(nrows, ncols, CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar::all(0));
    for(mwIndex c=0; c<ncols; c++) {
        for(mwIndex r=0; r<nrows; r++) {
            img.at<char>(r,c) = data[r + nrows*c];
        }
    }

    // process image before detection
    cv::equalizeHist(img, img);

    // detect faces
    std::vector<cv::Rect> faces;
    cascade.detectMultiScale(img, faces, 1.1, 4, 0, cv::Size(30,30));

    // return rectangles found to MATLAB
    plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(4, faces.size(), mxREAL);
    double *out = mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
    for(mwIndex i=0; i<faces.size(); i++) {
        out[i+0] = static_cast<double>(faces[i].x);
        out[i+1] = static_cast<double>(faces[i].y);
        out[i+2] = static_cast<double>(faces[i].width);
        out[i+3] = static_cast<double>(faces[i].height);
    }
}
```

Assuming you have download OpenCV 2.4.7 and extracted it into `C:\OpenCV` (with `sources` and `build` sub-directories beneath it), run the following command to compile the code:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -I'C:\OpenCV\build\include' -L'C:\OpenCV\build\x64\vc11\lib'
  -lopencv_core247 -lopencv_imgproc247 -lopencv_objdetect247 faces.cpp
```

(adjust the libraries path above according to your compiler. I'm using VS2012)

Next we test the MEX-function in MATLAB:

```
% some grayscale face image
img = imread('http://www.ece.rice.edu/~wakin/images/lena512.bmp');

% detect face
rect = faces('./haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml', img);

% show result
imshow(img)
rectangle('Position',rect(:,1), 'LineWidth',4, 'EdgeColor','g')
```

[image: face_detected]

Comment: I can compile the code above but not run it. Do I need to install mexopencv to run it? Or is my matlab not able to find dynamic libraries? My Error: "Error using faces! Failed to load cascade classifier" (I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, and a manually compiled OpenCV)

Comment: @mcExchange: no, the above example requires only OpenCV (although `mexopencv` certainly makes this process easier). As for the error message, you need to specify the full path to the XML file containing the pre-trained cascade classifier `'haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml'`. You can find those in [`C:\OpenCV\sources\data\haarcascades\*.xml`](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/data/haarcascades) (there's classifiers for detecting faces, eyes, ears, mouth, nose, etc..)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of OpenCV, but for newer versions, you will not find a `cxcore` library.  In 2.4.7 it is `opencv_core247d.lib` for the Debug build and and `opencv_core247.lib` for the Release build.  Look at the documentation for  the version of OpenCV that you are using. It sounds like you are using rather old instructions.

[This tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_Opencv/windows_visual_studio_Opencv.html#windows-visual-studio-how-to) provides instructions for building applications with OpenCV in Windows, and it lists the names of the libraries that you typically include. Obviously, the Visual Studio IDE instructions do not apply.

Based on the unresolved external symbols, you should probably link the following libraries:

- opencv_core247
- opencv_imgproc247
- opencv_objdetect247
- opencv_features2d247
- opencv_highgui247
- others?

This probably too many, but it won't hurt.

Comment: i'm using opencv 2.4.7.2

Comment: Then you would be looking for opencv_core247.lib or opencv_core247d.lib.